# why my database-java codes are not working on my project but working on the new one

Tags: java

I am new to java. I am trying to connect to mariadb from code written in eclipse IDE. Here is my code:

```java
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class DB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Connection connection = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/test";
        String user = "root";
        String pwd = "123456";
        
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("you are connected to database");
    }

}
```

This code is not working in my project; however, when I copied the code to the new java project then I'm not facing the problem and it is working. What could be the reason for this issue and how I can fix it?

Here is error message:

```java
Error: Main method not found in class DB, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Comment: We would need to see your project structure, and how you're attempting to run the code, to help you figure out what is going on.

Comment: Why do you have dependencies on JavaFX? Maybe you have created a javafx project, so the template is telling Eclipse to run a JavaFX application, but it's not a jfx app and fails. Meanwhile, the new project is correctly setup without the javaFX stuff, and runs properly because of that. We'd need your project structure and run configuration, if you are using gradle or maven, the build.gradle and/or pom would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DB` class doesn't need a `main` method. Also, your main method only specifies if you can connect to the database. You may not use this Connection object anywhere in your FX application. To use this `Connection` object in your `FX application`, you should use a method like the one below.

```
public class DB {

   private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(DB.class.getName());
   private static final String URL = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/test";
   private static final String USER = "root";
   private static final String PWD = "123456";

   public static Connection getDBConnection() {

       Connection connection = null;

       try {
           connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PWD);
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
       }
       return connection;
   }
}
```

Use this whenever you want to access the database at any point in your FX application.

```
Connection connection = DB.getDBConnection();
// Whatever you want to do with your Connection object.
connection...
```